# Linux truncate file

Tags: linux, filesystems

Here's a simple one. How do I truncate an existing file in linux? That is, how do I empty the contents of the file but keep the file. I can always delete the file then `touch` it but I was  wondering if there's a single command that'll get the job done.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`>output-file` -- shortest possible version.

Comment: accepted for shortness - btw what does the extra colon do in `:>output-file` ?

Comment: No idea; probably best to ask mezgani since he was the one who suggested it.

Comment: colon's a `noop`

Comment: This is the only correct answer.

Comment: @Xepoch: Thanks; I couldn't find it mentioned in `bash`(1), it's too common a character.  I suspected it was something like that, though.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is more efficient than cat, because it doesn't create a subprocess (in addition to the shell process):

```
true >output-file
```

Answer (score 2):

You may do easy :)

```
:>output-file
```

Comment: This is short and it works in all major shells I use (bash, dash, zsh, pdksh, tcsh).

Comment: yep, i think that not work on ksh

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure a harder-core *nix person will have a better idea, but I've always done:

```
cat /dev/null > output-file
```

To truncate files.

Answer (score 0):

echo -n > YOURFILE
will remove file contents and keep the file, structure and permission intact.

Answer (score 0):

There is also:

```
truncate --size 0 file
```

Available from gnu coreutils (and probably others too).

I think it reads better than `>file`, and `truncate` also have more options (see `truncate --help`).