# Why is this logfile not empty after truncating it?

Tags: linux

I have a 142MiB log file named c3600_router_log.txt under /tmp directory which is used by a process([Dynamips](http://www.gns3.net/dynamips/)):

```
root@potato:/tmp# lsof | grep c3600_router_log.txt
dynamips  12369        root   15w      REG                8,8  148101336         76 /tmp/c3600_router_log.txt
root@potato:/tmp#
```

I would like to delete the content of this log file. If I use `cat /dev/null >| c3600_router_log.txt` or `echo -n "" >| c3600_router_log.txt`, then file content is not deleted:

```
root@potato:/tmp# date +%T; ls -lh c3600_router_log.txt
01:44:07
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 142M 25. veebr 01:44 c3600_router_log.txt
root@potato:/tmp# date +%T; cat /dev/null >| c3600_router_log.txt
01:44:09
root@potato:/tmp# date +%T; ls -lh c3600_router_log.txt
01:44:11
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 142M 25. veebr 01:44 c3600_router_log.txt
root@potato:/tmp# date +%T; ls -lh c3600_router_log.txt
01:35:47
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 142M 25. veebr 01:35 c3600_router_log.txt
root@potato:/tmp# date +%T; echo -n "" >| c3600_router_log.txt
01:35:49
root@potato:/tmp# date +%T; ls -lh c3600_router_log.txt
01:35:50
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 142M 25. veebr 01:35 c3600_router_log.txt
root@potato:/tmp#
```

Nor is the file content flushed if I use the `> c3600_router_log.txt` option:

```
root@potato:/tmp# date "+%T"; ls -lh c3600_router_log.txt
02:11:55
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 189M 27. veebr 02:11 c3600_router_log.txt
root@potato:/tmp# date "+%T"; > c3600_router_log.txt
02:11:57
root@potato:/tmp# date "+%T"; ls -lh c3600_router_log.txt
02:11:58
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 189M 27. veebr 02:11 c3600_router_log.txt
root@potato:/tmp#
```

How to explain this behavior? Are there situations where one is not able to flush the content of the file which in use by a process?

Comment: This could be an interesting question, as it appears that the standard methods suggested in [Linux truncate file](http://serverfault.com/questions/90349/linux-truncate-file) are not working. However, your question is hard to read because of your use of `>|` (needed with `noclobber`) and `date "+%T"`. If you want a better response, I suggest you remove the extraneous noise, and avoid obscure options like `noclobber` so that your environment is more recognizable.

Comment: Are you running Linux?  Just that it's not entirely obvious from the question and the answers may be quite different for different operating systems.

Comment: Because the file is open by another process and is appending data.  If that process was to close and re-open the file then the size would update correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Knowing now that you have `noclobber` set (and having read the manpage on that) what you are doing above looks correct.  I would look elsewhere for the cause.

Can you try truncating the file using another method such as `vim` or a short `perl` script?  This isn't a solution, just hoping to determine whether it's bash that's causing the failure or the filesystem.  If we're lucky, maybe you'll get an error message out of one of those.

It doesn't look like the [exit status of the bash command](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html#EXITCODESREF) will be useful.  There's nothing specific in bash exit statuses about filesystem errors.

Alternatively you can try switching `noclobber` off and see if it starts behaving normally.  That would confirm that `noclobber` is the problem.

Also, try shutting Dynamips off and see if that makes any difference.

Some more guesses:

1. **Normal file locking:**

   Does another process have an exclusive lock on that file?  You can find these with one of:

   - `fuser /tmp/c3600_router_log.txt`
   - `lsof /tmp/c3600_router_log.txt`
   - `ls -i /tmp/c3600_router_log.txt` followed by `grep <inode> /proc/locks`.

   I don't expect this to turn up anything.  Your `lsof` output shows that file only being open by one process and not with an exclusive lock.  If there's a hard-link of that file it could be open with another process by a different filepath.  The above methods check by inode.  Since there's a process with a non-exclusive lock, there can't be another one with an exclusive lock, regardless of hard-links.
2. **Extended attributes:**

   Do you have any extended attributes for this file such as append-only?  You can check this with `lsattr /tmp/c3600_router_log.txt` and look for `a` in the output.  There may be other extended attributes that could cause the behaviour you are seeing such as an ACL.

   You can check ACLs with `getfacl /tmp/c3600_router_log.txt`.
3. **SELinux:**

   Are you running SELinux (or possibly AppArmor)?  You can check SELinux context fields with `ls -Z /tmp/c3600_router_log.txt` and `ps Z` for your shell.  I'm not familiar enough with AppArmor to be sure of the best method but it seems `aa-complain /etc/apparmor.d/*` would cause anything that would have been blocked to be logged and allowed instead.

Pick the line of investigation above that best suits your environment.

Failing all of that, try running an `strace` on your shell in another session while trying to truncate the file and see what error is returned when dealing with that file.

Comment: I'm using >| because I have `noclobber` option in bash enabled.

Comment: Ladada: See the bash manual : http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirecting-Output

Answer (score 0):

You can just `> c3600_router_log.txt` no point using pipe after >

Comment: It has a point if you have `noclobber` set in bash.